# Listing nonmissing string variables in Stata

Tags: string, stata

I want to display (`list`) the value of a string variable `DE15_WHY` in Stata only when it is not missing (e.g. some subjects did not provide comments). I thought this would be easy:

```
list DE15_WHY if DE15_WHY != ""
```

This displays `DE15_WHY` for all subjects even if they do not have anything in `DE15_WHY`...

Is the string formatted wrongly? For example, does Stata think that all subjects have a valid observation for `DE15_WHY`? How do I fix this? I checked, and it is formatted as a string variable.

Stata also allows me to `tabulate DE15_WHY`, similar to R. This is a great option but does not display the entire contents of the string variable in the table. How do I get Stata to display the entire string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Metrics' answer has several good details, but I will here add more.

With string variables, Stata has only one definition of missing, namely that a string is empty, and contains precisely no characters.

One or more spaces, despite usually conveying nothing to people, do not qualify as missing so far as Stata is concerned.

The term "blank" is perhaps unclear here and thus better avoided.

If spaces somehow get into your string variables a condition such as

```
   if trim(mystring) == ""
```

selects values that are empty or that have spaces and correspondingly a condition such as

```
   if trim(mystring) != ""
```

selects values with other content. To replace spaces with empty strings, we thus go

```
   replace mystring = "" if trim(mystring) == ""
```

In general, if you have rather long strings, Stata necessarily has a problem of where to display them. One tip is that `list` will show more than `tabulate`. If you want a `tabulate` and `list` hybrid, check out `groups` from SSC, using `ssc inst groups`.

Although the period `.` is the default or system missing value for numeric variables (or numeric scalars or matrix elements) in Stata, it does not attach any special meaning to the string `"."`.

Answer (score 2):

```
sysuse auto
list  rep78 in 1/10 if  rep78 !=. # for non-missing 
tab  rep78  # default behaviour is to report only non-missing
tab rep78, missing # if you want also missing
```

If variable is a string with missing indicated by `.`

```
list yourvariable if yourvariable !="."
```

If variable is a string with missing indicated by blank

```
list yourvariable if yourvariable !=""
```

Example:

```
my  my1
ab  1
cd  2
    3
ef  4

list  my if  my !=""

     +----+
     | my |
     |----|
  1. | ab |
  2. | cd |
  4. | ef |
     +----+
```

`tab` will treat both blank and . as missing.

.

```
 tab my

         my |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------+-----------------------------------
         ab |          1       33.33       33.33
         cd |          1       33.33       66.67
         ef |          1       33.33      100.00
------------+-----------------------------------
      Total |          3      100.00


tab my,missing

         my |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------+-----------------------------------
            |          1       25.00       25.00
         ab |          1       25.00       50.00
         cd |          1       25.00       75.00
         ef |          1       25.00      100.00
------------+-----------------------------------
      Total |          4      100.00
```

Comment: In addition, the condition `if trim(my) == ""` will catch cases of one or more blanks in a string variables `my`. For a string variable, missing means empty and vice versa.

Comment: > `tab` will treat both blank and `.` as missing.  <br/> I would add: ... when the variable is string and numeric, respectively. This confused me a bit because for a minute I thought `.` could represent a missing for string types.

Comment: Thanks @Metrics, however, != "" and != "." produce the same results. All subjects are displayed, those with blanks and those with string values, not the tidy output you get in your example. So how do I get tab to display the entire contents of the string  - it gets truncated at a certain length?

Comment: No problem. In that case, you need to provide the sample data, so that we can test our code.

Comment: Excellent @NickCox - your code when used as: list DE15_WHY if trim(DE15_WHY) != "" works!